# Permission of a mounted EXT4 for a specific user

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I basically stumbled upon a problem I need help with.
I mounted a HDD. In my /home folder I created several symlinks that point to folders on that HDD. Unfortunately I am unable to create the symlink for the Videos folder, however all other folders worked fine.

This is what I did

1. sudo mkdir /mnt/md0_crypt
2. sudo chown me:me /mnt/md0_crypt
3. sudo chmod 700 /mnt/md0_crypt
4. nano /etc/fstab: `UUID=LONG-NUMBER /mnt/md0_crypt ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,exec,auto,nouser,async,relatime        0       0`
5. Reboot
6. ```
   rm -r -f /home/me/Musik
   rm -r -f /home/me/Videos
   ln -s /mnt/md0_crypt/me/Musik /home/me/Musik
   ls -s /mnt/md0_crypt/me/Videos /home/me/Videos
   ```

When I try to create the Videos symlink it fails

```
ls: Access to '/home/me/Videos' not possible: File or directory not found
/mnt/md0_crypt/me/ videos:
0 in total
```

I used chmod 700, because I want to be the only user that has access to the mounted HDD. I don't know if I forgot something, mount related..

Interestingly I get this:

```
>>>ls -l /mnt/md0_crypt/me                                                                                              
total 52
drwx------ 13 me me 20480 25. Okt 2019   Musik
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 21. Jul 20:12  Videos
```

Comment: You forgot to `mount` the partition. Step 5 was performed on your `/mnt` filesystem. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld may help you see what's going on. BTW, the `auto` option is only used at system startup, when it does `mount -a`.

Comment: I forgot to add a reboot to my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typo, look at step 6 in your question:

- You removed `/home/me/Videos` with `rm -r -f /home/me/Videos`
- You used `ls` instead of `ln` in `ls -s /mnt/md0_crypt/me/Videos /home/me/Videos`, but you cannot `ls` this folder, you just removed it.

The error message says `ls: Access to '/home/me/Videos' not possible`, it's not complaining that `ln` fails, `ls` is failing.

Comment: Good eyes! Plus 1!

Comment: Man! Good eyes thank you!